# insertion failed in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

include('include/connection.php'); 
session_start();
$_SESSION['verify_remote_agent']=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$r=session_id();

if(isset($next))   {
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $from_city=$_POST['from_city'];
  $to_city=$_POST['to_city'];

  $query="INSERT INTO user_details values('$r','$city',$from_city,'$to_city')";
  mysql_query($query);
}

?>

<div class="container">
  <form action="index2.php" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group city col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control" name="city">
        <option value="choose">Choose City</option>
        <option value="option[1]">Delhi/NCR</option>
        <option value="others">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group from_city col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from_city" placeholder="From Area">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group to_city col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to_city" placeholder="To Area">
    </div>      

    <p class="text-right">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next Step" name="next">
    </p>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: $from_city needs quotations around it in the query, and you need to specify the columns in the user_details table. Also, are you connecting to the database correctly? I don't see an database connection instance in the code you provided above.

Comment: Firstly: This is now how to ask a question. Second: mysql is deprecated. Thirdly: You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: It would be helpful if you asked an actual question _in the body_ of your post. Don't forget to mention any error messages you get. Where does your code fail? How do you know it failed?

Comment: okay sir i'll remember that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $query="INSERT INTO user_details values('".$r."','".$city."','".$from_city."','".$to_city."')";

  mysql_query($query);
```